# Controllability for second order coupled system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

I have the following system:

$\ddot{y_1}=-y_1+\alpha y_2+u_1$

$\ddot{y_2}=-y_2+\alpha y_1-2u_2$

I am trying to answer 4 questions:

1. For what values of $\alpha$ is the system controllable
2. For what values of $\alpha$ is the system controllable from $u_1$ alone
3. For what values of $\alpha$ is the system controllable from $u_2$ alone
4. For what values of $\alpha$ is the system controllable if $u_1=u_2$

My workings:

First, let's convert it into state space form by setting

$x_1=y_1, x_2=y_2,x_3=\dot{y_1},x_4=\dot{y_2}$

We get

$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{x_1}\\\dot{x_2}\\\dot{x_3}\\\dot{x_4}\\\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\-1&\alpha&0&0\\\alpha&-1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\1&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\\end{bmatrix}$.

To answer 1) We check controllability by checking the rank of $[B,AB,A^2B,A^3B]$ with $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\\1&0\\0&-2\end{bmatrix}$. This matrix appears to always be full rank.

To answer 2) We check controllability by checking the rank of $[B,AB,A^2B,A^3B]$ with $B=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. This matrix appears to be full rank only when $\alpha\ne0$.

To answer 3) We check controllability by checking the rank of $[B,AB,A^2B,A^3B]$ with $B=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix}$ This matrix appears to be full rank only when $\alpha\ne0$.

To answer 4) We check controllability by checking the rank of $[B,AB,A^2B,A^3B]$ with $B=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix}$ This matrix appears to be full rank only when $\alpha\ne0$.

Are the answers really this trivial or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given a detailed solution for all the 4 parts using Kalman's test for controllability of a linear control system:

(a) When we work with two controls $u_1$ and $u_2$:

First we form the controllability matrix as
$$
Q = \left[ \matrix{B & A B & A^2 B & A^3 B \cr} \right]
$$
and calculate the rank of $Q$.

A simple calculation yields
$$
Q = \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -2 \alpha \\[2mm]
0 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & \alpha & 2 \\[2mm]
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -2 \alpha & 0 & 0 \\[2mm]
0 & -2 & 0 & 0 & \alpha & 2 & 0 & 0 \\[2mm]
\end{array} \right]
$$

Since the first columns of $Q$ are linearly independent,

$$
\mbox{rank}(Q) = 4
$$

Thus, we conclude that the linear system is controllable for all values of $\alpha$.

(b) When we work with one control only $u_1$.

In this case, we take
$$
B = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

The controllability matrix $Q$ reduces to
$$
Q = \left[ \matrix{B & A B & A^2 B & A^3 B \cr} \right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
  0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \alpha & 0 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

When $\alpha \neq 0$, the controllability matrix has full rank and the system is completely controllable.

When $\alpha = 0$, the controllability matrix has rank 3
and the system is not controllable.

(c) When we work with one control only $u_2$.

In this case, we take
$$
B = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
-2 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

The controllability matrix $Q$ reduces to
$$
Q = \left[ \matrix{B & A B & A^2 B & A^3 B \cr} \right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
  0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \alpha \\
0 & -2 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & -2 \alpha & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

When $\alpha \neq 0$, the controllability matrix has full rank and the system is completely controllable.

When $\alpha = 0$, the controllability matrix has rank 3
and the system is not controllable.

(d) When we work with $u_1 = u_2$.

In this case, we take
$$
B = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
-2 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

The controllability matrix $Q$ reduces to
$$
Q = \left[ \matrix{B & A B & A^2 B & A^3 B \cr} \right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
  0 & 1 & 0 & -2 \alpha - 1 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & \alpha + 2 \\
1 & 0 & -2 \alpha - 1  & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & \alpha + 2 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

When $\alpha = 0$, the matrix $Q$ has rank 2 as it has only two linearly independent columns. In this case, the system is not controllable.

When $\alpha \neq 0$, the matrix $Q$ has full rank and the system is completely controllable.

Comment: Isn't this what I did?

Comment: Kindly compare the controllability matrix you have given in the question and the controllability matrix in my answer. I spent some time to calculate this matrix correctly!

Comment: ohh sorry, I meant [B,AB,A2B,A3B], not [A,AB,A2B,A3B]! But I still did the calculations in my book. I am still getting the same answers: 
1) Always full rank
2,3,4) Only full rank when alpha not equal to 0.

Comment: Check my calculations for part 4) The system is controllable for all values of $\alpha$. I found Q using MATLAB.

Comment: I will double check my work for part 4), maybe I had made some mistake. Thank you so much sir for your effort!

Comment: hi sir. Actually for the last one where u1=u2, I am getting uncontrollable for $\alpha=0$. The rank appears to be 2. Is this correct?

Comment: When u_1 = u_2, system becomes single input. Use the matrix B I gave. The controllability matrix Q has full rank for all values of $\alpha \in R$. Check your calculations.

Comment: If you put $\alpha=0$ into your Q matrix, columns 1 and 3 are linearly dependent. As are columns 2 and 4 I think.

Comment: You are right. Let me edit my answer and correct it. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you as well for validating my answers!

Comment: If I may ask one more question: Say we have the output $y = <y_1, y_2>$, and we need to write it in form $y=Cx+Du$. Then in this case, will we have to rewrite as $y=<x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4>?$ Then we can form $y=<x_1,x_2,0,0> = Cx+Du$ using the C matrix, and D=0?

Comment: Yes, looks fine!

Comment: Also, wherever you said Rank 3, I think they should be Rank 2?